# Multinomial Regression with all categorical predictors

Tags: r, r-caret, categorical-data, multinomial, nnet

I have a dataframe that is 10191x2. My predictor variable is categorical and my response is also categorical. Below are some of the rows of this dataset:

```
df

Partner          Customer
      A             Alpha
      A              Beta
      B              Beta
      C             Gamma
      C             Alpha
      C              Zeta
```

I am trying to create a multinomial logistic regression model that will predict the probabilities of a customer buying on a specific partner. So my methodology is below:

To give you an idea, in this dataset there are 1385 partners and 53 Customers.

```
trainIndex <-createDataPartition(df$Customer, p=0.8,
                                 list = FALSE,
                                 times =1)
TRAINING <- df[trainIndex,]
TESTING <- df[-trainIndex,]

dummies <- dummyVars(Customer ~ ., data = TRAINING)
dummy<-data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = TRAINING))
df2<-cbind(dummy,TRAINING$Customer)
df2$`TRAINING$Customer`<-as.factor(df2$`TRAINING$Customer`)

model<-train(`TRAINING$Customer` ~.,data = df2,
  method = "multinom")
```

Then when I run this the following error comes up:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(`TRAINING$Customer` = c(5L, 18L, 14L, : missing values in object
```

I checked my initial dataset and there are no missing values so I am confused on why this is happening.

Would anyone be able to give some insight into why this error is occurring along with how to apply multinomial logistic regression to a dataset that has all categorical variables?

Comment: I can't understand what you're doing. Don't use special characters like `$` in column  names - that could cause some trouble. The way you describe things it sounds like you have only one predictor... a categorical variable, which would make multinomial regression overkill. And rather than check your initial data for missing values maybe it makes sense to check `df2` for missing values. And if you find any, check every step along the way to see where they are created...

Comment: Do you recommend a different ML algorithm for solving this problem? I am trying to obtain the probability of each customer buying by partner. So when I use the Test dataset, it will contain already existing partners. This is going to be used to better target customers in the end.

Comment: I mean, `prop.table(table(df), 2)` gives you that. You can't really do machine learning if you don't have data with features.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah I was thinking that I could make the Partners into dummy variables and that would be the features but since it would always just be one feature coming in at a time in the new dataset, then it wouldn't be possible to really do machine learning on it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you pick up assigning these names to variables?